# ASP.NET Membership Web-Based Administration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

Does anyone know if there's a way to manage users/roles in the asp.net membership database using a web-based interface you can access remotely?

I need one which doesn't require installation to the Default Website.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the asp .net object for managing users and membership information is fairly straightforward, why not do it yourself?

Comment: Seems that's what I'm going to have to do.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163807.aspx).
with samples of how to implement the aspnet membership database through webservices.
Download asp.net example from [here](http://www.idesign.net/idesign/DesktopDefault.aspx?tabindex=-1&tabid=19&download=146)
For the downloaded example using SQL express for local testing, I struggeled a little bit, but found a solution:
In web.confing:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=name of the local machine\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ASPNETDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and dirty solution. Copy your ASP.NETWebAdminFiles to a directory on your server. Make it a virtual directory. Open up the App_Code/WebAdminPage.cs file and coment out lines around 488 - 495 the code will look like this:

```
        // Changed by Jason so I can use this remotely!!!
        //  if (!application.Context.Request.IsLocal) {
        //    SecurityException securityException = new SecurityException((string)HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResources", "WebAdmin_ConfigurationIsLocalOnly"));
        //    WebAdminPage.SetCurrentException(application.Context, securityException);
        //    application.Server.Transfer("~/error.aspx");
        //  }
```

Then you can now use this tool remotely. Just user your browser to pull up the newly created virtual directory passing in the correct parameters. For example

```
http://myservername/WebAdminFiles/default.aspx?applicationPhysicalPath=C:\Websites\Application\&applicationUrl=/ApplicationURL
```

The other thing I did was to enable windows authentication on this folder so that I have to have an admin account on the server before I can access this url. This is important because once you enable this tool anyone can browse and delete users if they pull up the url.

Answer (score 1):

By the way the ASP.NETAdmin file are located on your machine here:

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles

enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

[MyWSAT](http://mywsat.codeplex.com/)

From the website:

> MyWSAT aka ASP.NET WSAT is a WebForms
>   based website Starter Kit for the
>   ASP.NET Membership Provider. It is a
>   feature rich application that takes
>   care of all the basics to save you
>   time. Use it as a template to start
>   your websites.

Comment: "Use it as a template to start your websites."

And infect your entire application with the GNU license

Comment: @anon - You are almost always going to have potential licensing "issues" when you use other people's code.  If you don't like that, you're always free to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

I just modify the connection string in my local web.config on the development version of my site to point to the remote database and then from within Visual Studio went to:

Project | ASP.NET Configuration

This opened up the local configuration site but talking to the remote database, allowing me to manage users/roles etc from there.

Obviously this assumes that you have a database server to connect to rather than the file based setup in APP_DATA.